# php session on undefinded constant

Tags: php, session

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant login - assumed 'login' in C:\wamp\www\Online_exam\header.php on line 43

Notice: Use of undefined constant login - assumed 'login' in C:\wamp\www\Online_exam\header.php on line 47

Notice: Use of undefined constant login - assumed 'login' in C:\wamp\www\Online_exam\index.php on line 30
```

I am new to PHP and learning SESSION, and i am trying to explore on that and i am receiving the above errors.  Everything looks correct for me.  Please somebody help me.

Index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Wel come to Online Exam</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<?php
   include("header.php");
    include("database.php");
    extract($_POST);

if(isset($submit))
{
    $rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_user where login='$loginid' and pass='$pass'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs)<1)
    {
        $found="N";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION[login]=$loginid;
    }
}
if (isset($_SESSION[login]))
{
echo "<h1 class='style8' align=center>Wel come to Online Exam</h1>";
        echo '<table width="28%"  border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="7%" height="65" valign="bottom"><img src="image/HLPBUTT2.JPG" width="50" height="50" align="middle"></td>
    <td width="93%" valign="bottom" bordercolor="#0000FF"> <a href="sublist.php" class="style4">Subject for Quiz </a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="58" valign="bottom"><img src="image/DEGREE.JPG" width="43" height="43" align="absmiddle"></td>
    <td valign="bottom"> <a href="result.php" class="style4">Result </a></td>
  </tr>
</table>';

        exit;


}


?>
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="70%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1%" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#CC3300"><span class="style6"></span></td>
    <td width="29%" bgcolor="#CC3333"><div align="center" class="style1">User Login </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="296" valign="top"><div align="center">
        <h1 class="style8">Wel come to Online Quiz</h1>
      <span class="style5"><img src="image/paathshala.jpg" width="129" height="100"><span class="style7"><img src="image/HLPBUTT2.JPG" width="50" height="50"><img src="image/BOOKPG.JPG" width="43" height="43"></span>        </span>
        <param name="movie" value="english theams two brothers.dat">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="movie" value="Drag to a file to choose it.">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="BGCOLOR" value="#FFFFFF">
<p align="left" class="style5">&nbsp;</p>
      <blockquote>
          <p align="left" class="style5"><span class="style7">Wel Come to Online 
            exam. This Site will provide the quiz for various subject of interest. 
            You need to login for the take the online exam.</span></p>
      </blockquote>
    </div></td>
    <td valign="top"><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="200" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td><span class="style2">Login ID </span></td>
          <td><input name="loginid" type="text" id="loginid2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="style2">Password</span></td>
          <td><input name="pass" type="password" id="pass2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><span class="errors">
            <?php
          if(isset($found))
          {
            echo "Invalid Username or Password";
          }
          ?>
          </span></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=2 align=center class="errors">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Login">       </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CC3300"><div align="center"><span class="style4">New User ? <a href="signup.php">Signup Free</a></span></div></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <div align="center">
        <p class="style5"><img src="images/topleft.jpg" width="134" height="128">          </p>
        </div>
    </form></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

Header.php

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="image/topbkg.jpg">
  <tr>
    <td width="90%" valign="top">
<!--You can modify the text, color, size, number of loops and more on the flash header by editing the text file (fence.txt) included in the zip file.-->
<div align="left"><object classid=clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000
codebase=http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,2,0
width=500
height=68>
<param name=movie value=image/fence.swf>
<param name=quality value=high>
<param name=BGCOLOR value=#000000>
<param name=SCALE value=showall>
<param name=wmode value=transparent> 
<embed src=image/fence.swf
quality=high
pluginspage=http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash type=application/x-shockwave-flash
width=500
height=68
bgcolor=#000000
scale= showall>
</embed>
</object></div></td>
    <td width="10%">
     <img border="0" src="image/topright.jpg" width="203" height="68" align="right"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000000" background="img/blackbar.jpg">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" align="right"><img border="0" src="image/blackbar.jpg" width="89" height="15"></td>
  </tr>
  </Table>
  <Table width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td>
  <?php "Hi ".$_SESSION[login]; ?>
  </td>
    <td>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION[login]))
    {
     echo "<div align=\"right\"><strong><a href=\"index.php\"> Home </a>|<a href=\"signout.php\">Signout</a></strong></div>";
     }
     else
     {
        echo "&nbsp;";
     }
    ?>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: You should be referring to `$_SESSION['login']` - note single quotes.

Comment: When will people learn to differ between erros (called "errors") and other things like warnings and notices?

Answer (score 0):

session variable should wrap with ' '...

change your session variable like this...

```
  $_SESSION['session_var_name'];
```

and in your case it should..

```
  $_SESSION['login']
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-numeric array key constants should be enclosed in quotes, either single or double. Otherwise, php thinks you are referring to a constant name. And since it's undefined, it falls back to guessing you just forgot the quotes...

That's why it works. And that's why the issue appears as a *Notice*. But in order to do away with it, change `$_SESSION[login]` to `$_SESSION['login']`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$_SESSION[login]`  into `$_SESSION['login']` in all occurance of your code

Comment: All the errors resolved, but getting the error in this line in HEADER.PHP.   Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\wamp\www\Online_exam\header.php on line 43                        This is Line 43  <?php "Hi ".$_SESSION['login']; ?>

Comment: <?php echo "Hi ".$_SESSION['login']; ?>

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the session name inside quotes only. Use

```
$_SESSION['login'] or $_SESSION["login"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Wel come to Online Exam</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<?php
include("header.php");
include("database.php");
extract($_POST);

if(isset($submit))
{
   $rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_user where login='$loginid' and pass='$pass'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs)<1)
    {
        $found="N";

    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['login']=$loginid;
    }
}
if (isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
echo "<h1 class='style8' align=center>Wel come to Online Exam</h1>";
        echo '<table width="28%"  border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="7%" height="65" valign="bottom"><img src="image/HLPBUTT2.JPG" width="50" height="50" align="middle"></td>
    <td width="93%" valign="bottom" bordercolor="#0000FF"> <a href="sublist.php" class="style4">Subject for Quiz </a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="58" valign="bottom"><img src="image/DEGREE.JPG" width="43" height="43" align="absmiddle"></td>
    <td valign="bottom"> <a href="result.php" class="style4">Result </a></td>
  </tr>
</table>';

       // exit;


}


?>
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="70%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1%" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#CC3300"><span class="style6"></span></td>
    <td width="29%" bgcolor="#CC3333"><div align="center" class="style1">User Login </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="296" valign="top"><div align="center">
        <h1 class="style8">Wel come to Online Quiz</h1>
      <span class="style5"><img src="image/paathshala.jpg" width="129" height="100"><span class="style7"><img src="image/HLPBUTT2.JPG" width="50" height="50"><img src="image/BOOKPG.JPG" width="43" height="43"></span>        </span>
        <param name="movie" value="english theams two brothers.dat">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="movie" value="Drag to a file to choose it.">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="BGCOLOR" value="#FFFFFF">
<p align="left" class="style5">&nbsp;</p>
      <blockquote>
          <p align="left" class="style5"><span class="style7">Wel Come to Online 
            exam. This Site will provide the quiz for various subject of interest. 
            You need to login for the take the online exam.</span></p>
      </blockquote>
    </div></td>
    <td valign="top"><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="200" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td><span class="style2">Login ID </span></td>
          <td><input name="loginid" type="text" id="loginid2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="style2">Password</span></td>
          <td><input name="pass" type="password" id="pass2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><span class="errors">
            <?php
          if(isset($found))
          {
            echo "Invalid Username or Password";
          }
          ?>
          </span></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=2 align=center class="errors">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Login">       </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CC3300"><div align="center"><span class="style4">New User ? <a href="signup.php">Signup Free</a></span></div></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <div align="center">
        <p class="style5"><img src="images/topleft.jpg" width="134" height="128">          </p>
        </div>
    </form></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>



<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="image/topbkg.jpg">
  <tr>
    <td width="90%" valign="top">
<!--You can modify the text, color, size, number of loops and more on the flash header by editing the text file (fence.txt) included in the zip file.-->
<div align="left"><object classid=clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000
codebase=http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,2,0
width=500
height=68>
<param name=movie value=image/fence.swf>
<param name=quality value=high>
<param name=BGCOLOR value=#000000>
<param name=SCALE value=showall>
<param name=wmode value=transparent> 
<embed src=image/fence.swf
quality=high
pluginspage=http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash type=application/x-shockwave-flash
width=500
height=68
bgcolor=#000000
scale= showall>
</embed>
</object></div></td>
    <td width="10%">
     <img border="0" src="image/topright.jpg" width="203" height="68" align="right"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000000" background="img/blackbar.jpg">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" align="right"><img border="0" src="image/blackbar.jpg" width="89" height="15"></td>
  </tr>
  </Table>
  <Table width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td>
  <?php 
   if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
  print "Hi ".$_SESSION['login']; 
  }
  ?>
  </td>
    <td>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
     echo "<div align=\"right\"><strong><a href=\"index.php\"> Home </a>|<a href=\"signout.php\">Signout</a></strong></div>";
     }
     else
     {
        echo "&nbsp;";
     }

    ?>


  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you.   All the errors resolved, but getting the error in this line in HEADER.PHP. Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\wamp\www\Online_exam\header.php on line 43 This is Line 43 <?php "Hi ".$_SESSION['login']; ?> –